# Mac: Cannot connect to SQL server through Docker

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql-server, macos, docker

I have an application which uses LocalDB and runs fine on a Windows PC, however I am trying to run this through my mac.... I'm struggling with connecting the application to a mySQL server which sits on docker. I have been following the other guides such as (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver15&pivots=cs1-bash) related to this topic with no luck...

Here's what I've done so far, through terminal:

- sudo docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU5-ubuntu-18.04
- sudo docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=<MyPassword123!>" 
  -p 1433:1433 --name sql_container 
  -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU5-ubuntu-18.04
- Verified this is running by using ***sudo docker ps -a***
  [image: Verified container running]
- Also verified by using Kitematic, container seems to be running well
- MySQL looks well set-up in System Preferences

[image: Image of System Preferences]

- I am able to connect to the container through Azure Data Studio using IP address as server name, as shown below

[image: Azure Data Studio]
[image]

- Within the Application, this is is what the ConnectionStrings look like within the appsettings.json folder...[image: appSettings.json]
- However, when I run the application and try and hit the container, through a GET request OR on Swagger, I am met with the following reply; ***"error": "Cannot connect to SQL Server Browser. Ensure SQL Server Browser has been started."***
- I have researched this and tried the solution of including the port number after the IP number as such ***Server=(19X.XXX.X.XX, 1433)*** but this also comes back with the error; ***"error": "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)"***

I'm not sure where to go from here... any help to get this working would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `Trusted_connection=True`, is not valid. It’s `Trusted Connection=True` but you can remove it completely since you are using username and password.

Comment: The `Connection string is not valid` part of the error message seems important here. Does your connection string work if you use `Sever=192.168.blah.blah,1433;Database=...`?

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts I have removed this now, no change in error, still showing "error": "Cannot connect to SQL Server Browser. Ensure SQL Server Browser has been started."

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I have tried to include the IP and Port as such Server=192.XXX.X.X, 1433 but error still shows   "error": "Cannot connect to SQL Server Browser. Ensure SQL Server Browser has been started."

Comment: `Ensure SQL Server Browser has been started.` Don't use an instance name, just use the server IP address and port. Instance name resolution requires the SQL Browser Service to be listening on udp/1434 and it then tells the connecting clients which tcp port a particular named instance is listening on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As trivial as it was, the correct syntax to make this work is Server=XXX.XXX.X.XX,1433

DO NOT INCLUDE PARENTHESES AND NO SPACE BETWEEN IP AND PORT